# Exclude id field from response

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

How can I exclude Id field from response in controller?

Here is my model:

```
public class Dog
{

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Breed { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Dog> GetDog()
    {
        //return from dog in _context.DogResponse select dog;
        return _context.Dog;
    }
```

Comment: Use `XmlIgnore` or `JsonIgnore` attribute depending on the output type.

Comment: you could use a DTO object which doesn't include fields you don't want to return. Most well-implemented web APIs don't directly return the DB model objects to the client.